# vector pointers and retrieving data

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner at coding in C++ and every other language. The problem I'm having here is in main() with the first (else if) where (UserInput == sell). I would like the function to print the data stored in the object @listPos to retrieve the cost and input it into my incomplete Profit() function, but every time I dereference the pointer (Search) I get an error code. There's something I'm missing big time please help!!

Ive already tried (*search) but there's a huge error code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class UnSold{

public:
UnSold(string NameOfShoe, int PurchasePrice ){
    name = NameOfShoe;
    cost = PurchasePrice;
    return;
}

void SetName(string NameOfShoe){
    name = NameOfShoe;
    return;
}
void SetCost(int PurchasePrice){
    cost = PurchasePrice;
    return;
}

string GetName() const {
    return name;
}
int GetCost() const{
    return cost;
}

void Profit();
void PrintItem();   
private:
    string name;
    int cost;
};
void UnSold::Profit(){
    static int profit = 0;
    //profit += (sold-cost);
}
void UnSold::PrintItem(){
    cout << "Name: " << this->name << " Cost: " << this->cost << endl;
}

void PrintEverything(vector<UnSold*> AllItems) {
    unsigned int i;

    for (i=0; i<AllItems.size(); ++i) {
        cout<< i+1 << " ";
        (*AllItems.at(i)).PrintItem();
    }

}
int main(){

    vector<UnSold*> Inventory;
    string Name;
    int Cost;
    string UserInput;
    unsigned int listPos;

    UnSold* newItem = nullptr;
    UnSold* search = nullptr; 

    while ( UserInput != "quit") {

        cout << "Do you want to add, sell, print or quit?" <<endl;
        cin >> UserInput;

        if ( UserInput == "add") {
            cout << "Enter item name: "<<endl;
            cin >> Name;
            cout << "Enter item cost: " << endl;
            cin >> Cost;
            newItem = new UnSold(Name, Cost);
            Inventory.push_back(newItem);
        }

        else if ( UserInput == "sell") {
            cout << "List Positon: ";
            cin >> listPos;
            if ( listPos < Inventory.size()){
                cout << " Item Sold and Removed from list position " << listPos <<endl;
                search = Inventory.at(listPos-1);


                //cout<< "contents of Search: "<< search << endl;

                delete search;
                Inventory.erase(Inventory.begin() + (listPos -1));
            }
            else{
                cout << "Error"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else if ( UserInput == "print") {
            PrintEverything(Inventory);
        }

        else if ( UserInput != "quit"){
        }


    }       


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error you say that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile error.
Remove line 85: `newItem.at(listPos - 1);` and it runs just fine in visual studio.

The issue is that `newItem` is a pointer to an element. I assume you meant to use `Inventory` here instead. However, that logic was already done on the previous line.

On a side note, I stongly advise against storing owning pointers like this. There's no good reason in this case not to just use `vector<UnSold>` instead.

Comment: i mildly advise against answering questions that are as unclear as this one before they have been clarified. OPs is talking about some different parts of the code and we dont know what is the error they are trying to fix (btw without compiling the code I also dont know what is the error you are refering to)

Comment: Yes i should of removed this line before posting(i was testing things), i will edit it right now sorry for the confusing. The code runs fine theres no errors im just looking to find out how can i get the data in the object specifically ( int cost) through my vector.

Comment: If i print out ( Search) it retruns the address of (listPos-1) to my understanding (*Search) is suppose to dereference the pointer to return the data values in my class UnSold @ listPos-1, but it returns an error.

Comment: @Mergim315 What do you mean by "returns an error"? Is it a compile error or a runtime error? What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
else if ( UserInput == "sell") {
    cout << "List Positon: ";
    cin >> listPos;
    if ( listPos < Inventory.size()){
        cout << " Item Sold and Removed from list position " << listPos <<endl;
        search = Inventory.at(listPos-1);


            //cout<< "contents of Search: "<< search << endl;

            delete search;
            Inventory.erase(Inventory.begin() + (listPos -1));
```

Here you mix the use of `listPos` and `listPos - 1`.

If you're allowing the user to input position 0 indexed, then

> `Inventory.at(listPos-1)` should be `Inventory.at(listPos)` 
>  and 
>   `Inventory.erase(Inventory.begin() + (listPos -1))` should be  `Inventory.erase(Inventory.begin() + (listPos))`.

**If you're letting them input the position with the indexing starting at 1**, then

> `if (listPos < Inventory.size())` should be 
>   `if(listPos <= Inventory.size() && listPos > 0)`

Comment: For the PrintEverything function i added 1 to ( i ) to start it at 1 intstead of 0.

Comment: You have to do it everywhere then. If you're allowing your list to be started at 1(from the user's perspective), anytime the user provides a list index, you have to subtract 1 from it. So make the changes mentioned for the second case.

As an example, you add an item to the list. That item is at Inventory[0]. To sell the item, the user would say they want to sell the first item on the list, so they input 1. Your conditional fails because listPos < Inventory.size() is false because they're both 1.  Also don't forget the second conditional check to make sure they don't input 0.